# dart:io sync vs async file operations

Tags: file, flutter, dart, async-await, dart-io

There are a number of sync and async operations for [files in `dart:io`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html):

- `file.deleteSync()` and `file.delete()`
- `file.readAsStringSync()` and `file.readAsString()`
- `file.writeAsBytesSync(bytes)` and `file.writeAsBytes(bytes)`
- and many, many more.

What are the considerations that I should keep in mind when choosing between the sync and async options? I seem to recall seeing somewhere that the sync option is faster if you have to wait for it to finish anyway (`await file.delete()` for example). But I can't remember where I saw that or if it is true.

Is there any difference between this method:

```
Future deleteFile(File file) async {
  await file.delete();
  print('deleted');
}
```

and this method:

```
Future deleteFile(File file) async {
  file.deleteSync();
  print('deleted');
}
```

Comment: use `sync` variants only in cases where you are sure it will finish in couple of milliseconds, not longer

Comment: @pskink, Even if I am in an async method?

Comment: yes, even in `async` method, btw `File` docs say: *"Most methods in this class occur in synchronous and asynchronous pairs, for example, readAsString and readAsStringSync. Unless you have a specific reason for using the synchronous version of a method, prefer the asynchronous version to avoid blocking your program."*

Comment: @pskink, I can certainly go with that, though on a deeper level I'd still like to know why. If I'm in an `async` method, then running the synchronous version isn't going to block the program any more than using `await` plus the asynchronous version would. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: well, try to read some half GB mp4 file and you will see... ;-)

Comment: @pskink Really? Would `file.readAsBytesSync()` for a large file block the program if it is in an async method? That's interesting. That fundamentally changes how I viewed async methods. I previously thought that anything that happens in an async method essentially runs on a different isolate.

Comment: yes, of course, do you think that you could create `for(var i=0; i<99999999999999999999999999999;i++)` and that loop would somehow work without blocking your app? in dart, by default, everything works in one thread - https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-part-2-a5592bef5213

Comment: and part 1 of course: https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-ccbca2543ae9

Comment: @pskink, Haha, yes, I did think that. And I just tried it and you were right (of course). It blocked my app. I still have some learning to do about isolates, threads in Dart, and async methods. Thanks for your help.

Comment: sure, your welcome, so you tried to run `readAsBytesSync` on a huge file?

Comment: @pskink no, I did a huge for loop.

Comment: aha, btw for using `Isolate`s there is a nice class: `IsolateChannel` which gives you a `Stream` / `Sink` 2 way communication  channel with `Isolate` - that way you can for example use `Sink.add` to submit new task for heavy processing and `Isolate` could return a result via `Stream` that you can `listen()` to

Comment: I believe that general rules for asynchronous I/O apply.  If you're going to perform a lot of I/O operations, using asynchronous I/O allows them to be batched together and should give better performance overall.  Making things a bit confusing is that there is an [`avoid_slow_async_io`](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_slow_async_io.html) Dart lint.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ah, yes, that's where I had seen that! Thank you. It would be nice to see an in depth explanation of the reason behind the `avoid_slow_async_io` lint some time.

Comment: @Suragch You perhaps could comment on https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36269 and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me try to summarize an answer based on the comments to my question. Correct me where I'm wrong.

- Running code in an `async` method doesn't make it run on another thread.
- Dart is a single threaded system.
- Code gets run on an event loop.
- Performing long running synchronous tasks will block the system whether it is in an async method or not.
- An isolate is a single thread.
- If you want to run tasks on another thread then you need to run it on another isolate.
- Starting another isolate is called spawning the isolate.
- There are a few options for running tasks on another isolate including [`compute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) and [`IsolateChannel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-stream_channel_isolate_channel/IsolateChannel-class.html) and [writing your own isolate communication code](https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-part-2-a5592bef5213).
- For File IO, the synchronous versions are faster than the asynchronous versions.
- For heavy File IO, prefer the asynchronous version because [they work on a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60735352/3681880).
- For light File IO (like `file.exists()`?), using the synchronous version is an option since it is likely to be fast.

#### Further reading

- [Isolates and Event Loops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vl_AaCgudcY)
- [Single Thread Dart, What? — Part 1](https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-ccbca2543ae9)
- [Single Thread Dart, What? — Part 2](https://medium.com/@parthdave93/single-thread-dart-what-part-2-a5592bef5213)
- [avoid_slow_async_io lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_slow_async_io.html)

Comment: Does it mean it's not necessary to spawn a separate isolate for async `file.writeAsBytes(bytes)` operation, as it will work on a separate thread automatically?

Comment: @SergeyMolchanovsky, Yes, that's my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`sync` variants unlike `async` ones stop the CPU from executing any event handlers - like the event loop, until the operation is complete.

- ##### Using `sync`:

  ```dart
  void main() {
    final file = File('...');
    Future(() => print('1')); // Adding to the event queue
    file.readAsBytesSync();
    print('2');
  }
  ```

  **Output:**

  ```
  2
  1
  ```
- ##### Using `async`:

  ```dart
  void main() async {
    final file = File('...');
    Future(() => print('1')); // Adding to the event queue
    await file.readAsBytes();
    print('2');
  }
  ```

  **Output:**

  ```
  1
  2
  ```

Comment: While I agree with your explanation, it may not be obvious to some readers that `print('2')` in the async example is also added to the event queue due to the fact that it occurs after the `await` in the function. That is, it's like nesting it in a `file.readAsBytes().then` callback.