# Sync or Async variant file functions inside onPressed calls in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I need to process files on onPressed event of a button. I see that functions like readAsBytes and length has sync and async variants. Which ones should I use for such processing?

Comment: Use async. Because this will be the most preferred method. Since if it you are reading a large file then the app will be stalled for a considerable amount of time if you use synchrous process

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61420070/8097519

Comment: most likely, instead of calling `readAsBytes` (which reads the entire file contents as a list of bytes) you should use `File.openRead` and process your data by means of `Stream`s (unless your files are couple of kB in size of course)